# Find all the ideals of $\mathbb { Z } [ i ]$ containing $(5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> **Problem** : Find all the ideals of  $\mathbb { Z } [ i ]$ containing $(5)$, the principal ideal generated by $5$.

I already know that $\mathbb { Z } [ i ]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{ Z }[x]/(x^2+1)$ but I have troubles getting an intuitive interpretation of polynomial rings and quotient rings. Should I be looking for principal ideals generated by polynomial with $5$ as a root?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The set of ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ containing $(5)$ corresponds bijectively to the set of ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(5)$.

Comment: We also showed that $\mathbb { Z } [ i ] / ( 5 ) \cong \mathbb { Z } / 5 \times \mathbb { Z } / 5$ (as a ring). Since $5$ is prime can I say that the only ideals of $\mathbb { Z } / 5 \times \mathbb { Z } / 5$ are $\mathbb { Z } / 5 \times \mathbb { Z } / 5$ and the null ring?

Comment: This is false; there are more ideals. Note that every ideal is in particular a subgroup; this doesn't leave many options. Also note that $5$ is not prime in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. If it were, then $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(5)$ would be an integral domain.